# Get data from async function and update state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios, use-state

I have created a variable using `useState` and that is an empty array.

`const [data, setData] = useState([]);`

I am calling an async function inside `useEffect` that is helping me to get all the data and update the data when received

```
useEffect(() => {
    //
    const items = [];
    async function fetchData() {
      items = await getAllItems();   //it should wait for data and then setData
      setData(items);    
    }
    fetchData();
    console.log("from useEffect", items);  // still items array is empty
  }, []);
```

Here is my imported data retrieving function which uses `Axios` and returns the data:

```
export const getAllItems = async () => {
  const url = baseUrl + "/items/getAllItems";
  await axios({
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    url: url,
  }).then((res) => {
    return res;  // when console logged we get a proper array if data
  });
};
```

But nothing works all I am getting back is `object of promise`. Could anyone guide me what I am missing out in my code?

Comment: Setstate is asynchronously, you can not see updated data in console log after setstate. Use useEffect dependency for updated data

Comment: I have tried making this call outside useEffect and then updating it in useEffect but that also not works

Comment: Can you see items in console log before setData(items)??

Comment: Change const items to let items.

Comment: yeah that works @NijatAliyev but still state is not updated

Comment: State updated :) but look at my first comment. If you see updated data, write second useEffect like this useEffect(() => {
    console.log("from useEffect", data);
  }, [data]);

Comment: basically now there is an error .map is not a function. I dont know why array is being shown as an object here hence cannot map within it

Comment: Check is your api response array or object, then write some condition in html. If data have then map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the value of `getAllItems()` to a constant variable `items` that has already been declared here:

```js
const items = [];
```

However, as per the [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const):

> The value of a constant can't be changed through reassignment (i.e. by using the assignment operator), and it can't be redeclared (i.e. through a variable declaration).

So you need to either initialize that variable using `let`, or better yet assign it immediately as follow:

```js
const items = await getAllItems();
```

You can then get rid of `const items = [];`

Comment: I messed up with my jsx syntax thats why it was creating an issue. Could you please add some explanation as it will help others .

Comment: we can use this or declare items as `let`  that will also help and to stop re rendering in endless loop remove the name of variable from the useEffect array or else it will keep on re rendering infinite times

Comment: @Ashishsah Did my answer allow to solve your problem by itself or was there some other issue that needs to be included as well ?

Comment: well I guess there were few mistakes by my side. Well I am editing your answer.

Comment: @Ashishsah I added explanations to the point mentioned in my answer. Feel free to add more to it if needed.

Comment: @Ashishsah Since we edited simultaneously your edit is based off an older version of my answer, so I re-edited it with some elements from your edit.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't return the data from the axios call.

```js
export const getAllItems = async () => {
  const url = baseUrl + "/items/getAllItems";
  const { data } = await axios({
    method: "GET",
    withCredentials: true,
    url: url,
  });
  return data;
};
```

Comment: that is not working

Comment: if you console.log items before setData is called what is shown?

Answer (score 0):

Your console.log() is in the wrong position (2). Should be in the position marked with (1) instead. Please check the comments I added:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const items = [];
    async function fetchData() {
      items = await getAllItems();   //it should wait for data and then setData
      setData(items);
      // (1) you chould console.log() the items array here instead
      // if the data is properly returned from getAllItems() it will be visible here
      console.log("from useEffect", items);
    }
    fetchData();
    console.log("from useEffect", items);  // (2) items array will be empty here right after fetchData() as getAllItems() has not returned yet.
  }, []);
```

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.` this is what i get

Comment: Try changing `const items = []` to `let items = []`. Like the error says you cannot reassign a `const` variable (although you can e.g. `.push()` to it, here it will be completely reassigned).

Comment: Or even better: do what @monstar said and assign directly to `const`.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
   let isMounted = true 
   function fetchData() {
      const items = axios.get(baseUrl + "/items/getAllItems")
      if (isMounted) setData(items);    
   }
   fetchData();
   return () => {isMounted = false}
}, []);
```